# How to position the cursor on the previously opened buffer in netrw?

Tags: vim, neovim

I like to "explore" and move around using netrw but one thing I don't like is whenever I come back to netrw, the cursor is always at the top.

I'd like to have the cursor automatically positioned on the last opened buffer if it is currently visible in netrw.

---

I have been thinking about it and it does not seem so easy to do.
I guess I'd need to:

- setup an autocommand that triggers on opening netrw, probably
- get the previously opened buffer if there is one (let's call it **foo**)
- list files of current directory in netrw
- find the position of **foo**
- if found, move the cursor there

But I have no idea how to do most of this.

Or maybe it is possible to get the last cursor position in netrw?

Comment: How do you "come back to netrw"? When I open a buffer from Netrw and then come back to it via `:Rex` or `<C-^>`, the cursor is where it was when I left.

Comment: @romainl ha! I was using `:ex`. But `:Rex` works indeed! Thank you. You can write this in an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

By searching for possible actions in netrw, I realized I could simply open files in a new tab with `t` which, in my case is somewhat equivalent to `<Enter>` because I don't use tabs.

The added benefit is that I can close the file and be back in netrw where I was.

Not the solution I had in mind at first but this solves my problem.